# MySQL how to rounded value to ceil

Tags: mysql

I tried to increase my product table price from 25%,
so I wrote a query like this,

```
UPDATE products set price = price * 1.25;
```

but i have to round final value to ceil.
eg:

old price: 0.73
wanted price: 0.92

but mysql given value: 0.9125

how to round mysql value to 0.92, please someone help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE products 
set price = ceil(price * 1.25 * 100) / 100
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/38967)

Comment: thank you fro feedback, but this retrun, 0.91, form 0.73*1.25, how to get this value 0.92

Answer (score 0):

use ROUND()

```
 UPDATE products set price = ROUND(price * 1.25, 2)
```

REFER: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round